# Animate the process of tab switching

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

Anyone have a walk around on animating the process when switching tabs?

I am currently doing this with 2 issues.

1: It messes up my UIControl colors. 
2: It switches the tab first, thereafter perform the animation.

I want to implement something like the effect when pushing a view to navigation stack.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:bookingVC.view cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Right now I am doing this, which doesn't have any animation effect.

```
NSArray *tabBarVC = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
UINavigationController *firstTabNC = [tabBarVC objectAtIndex:0];
BookingViewController *bookingVC = (BookingViewController *)[[firstTabNC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[bookingVC setNSStringProperty:newString]; //this string will be displayed on a UITextField whenever viewDidAppear; 

// So, I need some animation here when I switch tabs to make it more obvious that the UITextField is updated.
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

I am totally clueless on creating my own animation, please do guide me along. I am opened to ideas to better the presentation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you need to use the pre-iOS4 way of animating? Animation blocks simplify this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                 animations:
 ^{
      // show your desired view however you do it
 }
                 completion:
 ^(BOOL finished) {
      [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
 }];
```

---

*EDIT:* Sorry, I didn't pick up you were doing a view transition somehow.. silly. There's another block-based method for that case:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:bookingVC.view
                  duration:1.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionsTransitionCurlUp
                animations:
 ^{
     // do view transitioning here
 }
                completion:
 ^(BOOL finished) {
     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
 }];
```

---

*EDIT 2:* Alright, so you seem to need some help with the context of all this. You should be animating changes to active tabs in the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol (which your custom class would implement). In particular, the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method.

I'd recommend you first override the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method to make sure that you don't accidentally animate a transition from a tab to the same tab:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
  shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return viewController != [tabBarController selectedViewController];
}
```

In `didSelectViewController:`, do the animation. I'm also going to take this opportunity to rework your code, because if you're doing it within this method then the `selectedIndex` of the tab bar controller is handled automatically, and whatever you were doing with `bookingVC.view` can be replaced by a direct transition between the active tab controller and the new (selected) one:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:[tabBarController selectedViewController].view
                        toView:viewController.view
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionsTransitionCurlUp |
                               UIViewAnimationOptionsShowHideTransitionViews
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Note here that I use `UIViewAnimationOptionsShowHideTransitionViews` as part of your animation options. I'm doing this because our animation is on top of the system already changing the active tab, so we don't want to muck it up by trying to remove the view from the view heirarchy at the same time as the system is.

Comment: @darvidsOn. What should I fill in the `do view transition here`. I thought the `options:` parameter already stated what animation I wanted?

Comment: Yes but you haven't chosen what state to transition the view from and to. You need to rearrange or move or hide/unhide whatever elements you want to as part of the transition.

Comment: Sorry but I really am clueless on this. Could you explain in a more layman terms? I don't need anything fanciful, just want to animate the process of the tab switching after setting a property of the tab.

Comment: I assume doing these will animate the process of all tab switching? Which is not what I wanted, I only want it to be animated only at a particular time(after setting a property). I have edited my question to show what I am trying to implement.

Comment: Well then wrap the animation in an `if` statement and make sure it only gets run in the right conditions. And set the `NSStringProperty` right before you do the animation. I'm sure you already knew to do that.

Comment: The delegate methods don't seems to get called when I switch tabs even though I have inplemented the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` for my class. `@interface FavouriteListViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate>` This is the class that will set the property and switch tab thereafter.

Comment: Well, you need to set the `delegate` of the tab bar controller to `File's Owner` in Interface Builder before they're called.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your animation sequence in `didSelectItem:`:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

Then set up a modalView controller and animate the page curl effect from there.

Comment: Exactly, animating the selection of the tab won't do anything for you.